# How to animate a single raster layer with variable substitution SLD Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, animation

I was trying to animate a single raster layer with a variable substitution in SLD. I've followed the Geoserver documentation http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html#sld-variable-substitution 
How can I animate a single layer by using a variable substitution on Geoserver Style? This is part of the style I was using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptorxmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"mlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0"si:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sldhttp://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
<NamedLayer>
  <Name>Umidade Relativa Mínima</Name>
  <UserStyle>
     <Name>Style</Name>
     <Title>Style for a Coverage layer.</Title>
     <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
           <RasterSymbolizer>
              <ChannelSelection>
                 <GrayChannel>
                    <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>
                 </GrayChannel>
              </ChannelSelection>
              <ColorMap type="ramp">
                 <ColorMapEntry color="#ff0000" quantity="0.60" opacity="${env('op',0)}" label="20" />
                 <ColorMapEntry color="#00ff00" quantity="0.70" opacity="1.0" label="30" />
              </ColorMap>
           </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
     </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
```

and this is the query I was using to try to animate:
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/animate?&format=image/gif;subtype=animated&format_options=gif_loop_continuosly:true&layers=terrama2_4:view4&aparam=op&avalues=0;0.2;0.5;1

Comment: what does happen? is there an error message?

Comment: When I checked the Geoserver Log, it doesn't show any error message. It appears like a normal layer request. the parameters I've sent in the query are there in the log and nothing happens.

Comment: Could you add the GeoServer version you're using?

Comment: I'm using Geoserver 2.11.1

Answer (score 2):

The animator does not set environment variables (not directly), check the documentation for animator and environment variables:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/animreflector.html#overview
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html

It says that "aparam" is a KVP parameter replaced in the request. So with that setup you'll end up adding "&op=0", then "&op=0.25" and so on, which does nothing since the "op" parameter is unknown.

To make it do what you want something like this might work "aparam=env&avalues=op:0,op:0.25,op:0.5,op:1" so that the expansion would add "&env=op:0" then "&env=op:0.25" and so on.

I agree that setting directly env variable would be nice, if you want that to happen follow this guide:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer

Comment: Well, I used the parameters like you said, but it isn't working yet. I've tried to send the parameters like you suggest me "aparam=env&avalues=op:0,op:0.25,op:0.5,op:1" and the layer still static.